# Possible JCFs for $A \in M_5(\mathbb{C})$ satisfying $A^2(A-2)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having a hard time coming up with all possible Jordan Canonical Forms for $A$.  Here is what I have.

Let $f(x) = x^2(x-2)^2$.  It must be the case that $m_A(x) \mid f(x)$ which implies that the only possible eigenvalues for $A$ are $0$ and $2$.  Since we know nothing about the characteristic polynomial for $A$, I am not convinced that both $0$ and $2$ must be an eigenvalues for $A$.  I am thinking that the possibilities for $m_A(x)$ are: $x, x^2, (x-2), (x-2)^2, x(x-2), x(x-2)^2, x^2(x-2),$ or $x^2(x-2)^2$.  Can someone either confirm or tell me why this is false?

Once I have all possibilities for $m_A(x)$, the multiplicity of each root tells me the (maximum?) size of the Jordan block(s) corresponding to each root (eigenvalue).  So then if $m_A(x) = x(x-2)$, I can only have Jordan blocks of size 1 for both the eigenvalues $0$ and $2$ making a total of $4$ possible JCFs in this case?

If $m_A(x) = x^2(x-2)^2$, then all Jordan blocks for eigenvalues $0$ and $2$ have size $2$ which means this minimal polynomial is not possible for $A$? Can I still have Jordan blocks of size $1$ with $m_A(x) = x^2(x-2)^2$.

If someone could clear up my confusion I would be grateful.

**EDIT:**
Here is what I have after giving this some more thought.  Feedback would be much appreciated.

I found $7$ possible minimal polynomials for $A$ ($m_i(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$) listed below with corresponding possible characteristic polynomials $p_i(x)$:

$m_1(x) = x$, $p_1(x) = x^5$

$m_2(x) = x^2$, $p_2(x) = x^5$

$m_3(x) = x-2$, $p_3(x) = (x-2)^5$

$m_4(x) = (x-2)^2$, $p_4(x) = (x-2)^5$

$m_5(x) = x(x-2)$, $p_5(x) = x^4(x-2), x^3(x-2)^2, x^2(x-2)^3,$ or $ x(x-2)^4$

$m_6(x) = x^2(x-2)$, $p_6(x) = x^4(x-2), x^3(x-2)^2$, or $x^2(x-2)^3$

$m_7(x) = x^2(x-2)^2$, $p_7(x) = x^3(x-2)^2$ or $x^2(x-2)^3$.

If all seven of these minimal polynomials are possible (can someone confirm or tell me why this is correct?) then I found a total of $16$ possible JCFs for $A$.

Comment: By the Cayley Hamilton theorem, the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial. But the characteristic polynomial must also divide some power of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Worth emphasizing that your title says the dimension is $5.$ What are the possible characteristic polynomials?